# Не запускается zabbix на локалхосте

Tags: linux, centos, zabbix

ставлю Centos 8 minimal на виртуалку, после выполнения всех необходимых команд пытаюсь запустить localhost/zabbix в браузере, получаю "Попытка соединения не удалась". Также:
ip address выдает два ip - localhost и 192.168.2.50 (второй поставил с помощью nmtui, раньше был  10.0.2.15)
Не могу посмотреть лог заббикса в /var/log/zabbix_server, получаю no such file or directory.
Ставил все с помощью ctrl-C - ctrl-V, я новичок, даже не админ.

Comment: этого демона, наверно, надо запустить. `$ /etc/init.d/имя start`

Comment: 1. С хоста с которого пытаетесь зати пинганите IP адрес zabbix сервера.                                               2. Проверьте на zabbix сервере systemctl status zabbix-server.                                                      3. На zabbix сервер выключите selinux.                                                                                       4. Скорее всего проблема с iptables, нужно выключить